# Is it possible to install more than one themes in OpenCart?

Tags: installation, themes, opencart

I've googled and searched within the forum for an answer but couldn't find one. I'm new to Opencart and I'm just setting up my store. Is it possible to install more than 1 theme? I purchased 1 recently then purchased 1 today that I think will be better. Do I need to uninstall the first theme for the installation of new theme.If it is possible to have more than one themes in one opencart then please inform if any bugs or problems exists in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can just upload the new theme via FTP. Then go to System -> Settings -> Store Name and click the edit button.

On the 'Store' tab you should see 'Template' with a select menu, if you uploaded the theme correctly it will be listed there. Just select it and click the save button at top right.

Comment: i tried , its applicable for installation of first theme in opencart when ever i tried to install more then one themes all themes first installed theme becomes full of bugs or stop working due to some errors

Comment: I would suggest switching back to the default theme, then deleting the other themes. If that works then the problem must be with the themes you are trying to install.

Are the themes you are installing compatible with the version of Opencart you are running ?

Comment: thanks for your comments now I know that what was the problem actually there are more chances that more then one installed themes will may not work properly because if the theme we are installing is very complex then it will come with his own setting ,modules etc. thats why when it will start working then other theme will may not work or may work with missing functionalities.